# assign values to list<String[]>

Tags: java, android, list

i need your help because I may not have understood it well.

This `List<String[]> dataList` defines an list with string arrays, right?
So lets say that I have this values:

```
info[0], info[1], name[0],name[1]
```

How can I assign them to the above list, grouped by index? I mean the info[0] be with name[0], and so on. I want this is because later in my code I will use this:

```
public FacilitiesAdapter (List<String[]> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }
```

and I need my datalist to have in each row, the data I want. Have I understood something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this??

```
List<String[]> dataList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String name[] = new String[]{"n1","n2"};
        String info[] = new String[]{"i1","i2"};

        for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++)
        {
            dataList.add(new String[]{name[i],info[i]});
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Define it as a class:

```
public class MyData {
    public String info;
    public String name;
}
```

Then you have:

```
List<MyData> mDatalist;

public FacilitiesAdapter (List<MyData> dataList) {
    this.mDataList = dataList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
public void arrayLearning(){
    List<String[]> dataList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] info = {"first info", "second info"};
    String[] name = {"first name", "second name"};
    dataList.add(new String[]{info[0], name[0]});
    dataList.add(new String[]{info[1], name[1]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way :

```
List<String[]> dataList = new List<String[]>();
int len = info.length;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    dataList.add(new String[] {name[i], info[i]});
```

However, Calvin's answer is better for flexibility. If you want to add an additional field later, it will be way easier if you already created your own class instead of using a String array.

Answer (score 0):

Create the list

```
String[] name = new String[] { "name1", "name2" };
String[] info = new String[] { "info1", "info2" };
List<String[]> dataList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
   String[] item = new String[2];
   item[0] = name[i];
   // info and name must have the same size or you need some checks here
   item[1] = info[i];
  dataList.add(item);
}
```

print it

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
    Log.d("TAG", "item " + i + 
            " name:" + dataList.get(i)[0] + 
            " info:" + dataList.get(i)[1]);
}
```

use in your adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String[] item = datalist.get(position);
    String name = item[0];
    String info = item[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use data encapsulation if multiple data types is bound to one unique data. Calvin's method is the best suited and highly flexible.